Using Komm python library for modulation and demodulation how do I specify the frequency the signal is on?
library for reference https://komm.dev/ref/.
I am trying to modulate and demodulate some bits in code. the problem is I need to simulate  modulation sending and receiving the signal on a specific frequency and the library only does this around zero, how does one put this signal onto a specified frequency and then demodulate it on the receive side?

To move the complex baseband signal to a real carrier, multiply the signal with $e^{j\omega_c t}$ where $\omega_c$ is the carrier frequency of interest, and then take the real part of that product (producing the complex conjugate spectrum we would expect to see for a real passband signal.)
However, if this is for the purposes of modelling and simulation, then I would caution against doing that-- it really serves no purpose and requires many more samples to simulate the underlying carrier --- only to find out that anything that would happen at the real passband signal can equally be applied to the complex baseband signal directly.  Just stick with the baseband signal as created, and if you want for any plots or visualization to represent the passband signal, just change $f=0$ on the spectrum created to be $f=f_c$, and all will be the same. (It doesn't matter what the carrier is, so you may as well use DC as the carrier as long as the signal is represented in complex form).

So after further reading I need to simulate a passband signal (preferably by creating the signal with the library) then upconverting  and then convert it back to baseband on the receive side and pick out a signal on a specific frequency - I did not know these terms before. The available library(s) seems to create only signals around the baseband

After further reading what? I was trying to make the point that you do not need to simulate a passband signal—- I can’t think of any case where that would be necessary since all passband effects can instead be simulated at baseband. However I detailed here how you can translate the complex baseband signal you have to a real passband if you still wanted to do that.

Reading - just general dsp stuff online... I didnt know the term, I also just learned that things are downconverted onto baseband from the SDR (I think)  - I can see that e^jωct shifts my signal over to the wc (specified freq) but what I dont undersand is why my signal looks like it spans my entire bandwidth instead of it being a higher bump at the freq on the PSD
